# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-2.7, encoding, int, python-unicode

I encounter an error running a script I wrote on an Ubuntu box with python 2.7.
It seems there is some issue with unicode yet I cannot figure it out.

I tried to encode the variables with UTF-8 yet im not even sure which one causes the error "str(count)" or "tag[u'Value']..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./AWS_collection_unix.py", line 105, in <module>
    main()
  File "./AWS_collection_unix.py", line 91, in main
    ec2_tags_per_region(region, text_file)
  File "./AWS_collection_unix.py", line 65, in ec2_tags_per_region
    print_ids_and_tags(instance, text_file)
  File "./AWS_collection_unix.py", line 16, in print_ids_and_tags
    text_file.write('%s. %s' % (str(count), tag[u'Value']))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The error doesnt specify in which parameter the error is..

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xbf' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I make this work appropriately?

Thanks

Comment: Your `locale` setting has ASCII as encoding, so (in theory) it cannot display characters above 127 (and in any case python has no idea on how to encode them).  Make sure you will not use characters above 127 or change your locale.

Answer (score 0):

The shorties solution is to warp count with ->  unicode(count).encode('utf-8'),
What will convert count to be utf-8 encoded str.
But the best way is to understand what is the encoding of the count variable.